# Unable to use SwiftyJSON to access JSON data

Tags: json, swift, xcode, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm trying to access some JSON data but I can't access that using swiftyJSON. I'm getting JSON response back so I'm acquiring it using alamofire. Here's the JSON:

```
{"groupID":"6","groupName":"Test","teacher":"teacher1 
","teacherID":"13","Locations": 
[{"locationID":"5","locationName":"field"}, 
{"locationID":"6","locationName":"34th"}],"Error":""}
```

I'm using print statements to debug what's wrong. Here's the code that I'm trying to use:

```
                    let json = JSON(response.result.value ?? "error")
                    //let jsonError = json["Error"]
                    print("=================<JSON RESPONSE>=================");
                    print(json)
                    print("=================</JSON RESPONSE/>=================");

                    self.groupID = json["groupID"].stringValue
                    self.groupName = json["groupName"].stringValue
                    self.teacherID = json["teacherID"].stringValue
                    let locjson = json["Locations"]


                    print("Entering LocJSON Loop")
                    print("=================<LOCJSON >=================");
                    print("GNAME:" +  self.groupID)
                    print("TID: " + json["teacherID"].stringValue)
                    print("Locjson.stringalue: " + locjson.stringValue)


                    //print("LocationJSON" + json["Locations"]);
                    print("=================</LOCJSON/>=================");

                    for (key, object) in locjson {
                        print("In LocJSON Loop")
                        let locationIDVar: Int? = Int(key)
                        self.locations[locationIDVar!].locationID = locationIDVar!
                        self.locations[locationIDVar!].locationName = object.stringValue
                        print(self.locations[locationIDVar!].locationName)
                        print(object);
                    }
```

Here's the output from console that corresponds to the print statements.

```
=================<JSON RESPONSE>=================
{"groupID":"6","groupName":"Test","teacher":"Teacher1"         
,"teacherID":"13","Locations": 
[{"locationID":"5","locationName":"field"}, 
{"locationID":"6","locationName":"34th"}],"Error":""}
=================</JSON RESPONSE/>=================
Entering LocJSON Loop
=================<LOCJSON >=================
GNAME:
TID: 
Locjson.stringalue: 
=================</LOCJSON/>=================
```

Also, how do I get to the multiple locations that are inside 'Locations'?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. you can verify from this. https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

The value for key `Locations` is an array containing dictionaries.

```
    let locjson = json["Locations"].arrayValue
    for location in locjson {
        let locID = location["locationID"].stringValue
        let locName = location["locationName"].stringValue
        print(locID, locName)
    }
```

In Swift 4 I'd prefer `Decodable` over SwiftyJSON because you can directly decode into structs.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that. Any clue why json["groupID"].stringValue is not returning anything in print?

Comment: For a JSON `String` source you have to use the `init(parseJSON:` initializer.